# Under what conditions, the following equation may not hold: $A = B X$, where $A \in M_{m,n}$ and $B \in M_{m,p}$ are given, and $X \in M_{p,n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry for asking a basic question.
Under what (non-trivial) conditions the following equation will not hold?

\begin{align}
A = BX,
\end{align}
where $A \in M_{m,n}$ and $B \in M_{m,p}$ are given, and $X \in M_{p,n}$ is a variable?

The straight forward solution is
$X = B^{\dagger} A$, where $()^{\dagger}$ is pseudo inverse. But I wonder, will the solution always exist?

---

Numerically (in MATLAB), I see the solution exist for all my tests (see two them)...

```
A = rand(2,28) +1j*randn(2,28);
B = rand(2,4) +1j*randn(2,4);
X = pinv(B)*A;

% check whether the result is nearly zero. If yes, then good!
sum(sum((A - B*X))) 

ans =

   4.6352e-15 - 1.6209e-15i
```

```
A = rand(1,4) +1j*randn(1,4);
B = rand(1,2) +1j*randn(1,2);
X = pinv(B)*A;

% check whether the result is nearly zero. If yes, then good!
sum(sum((A - B*X)))  

ans =

  -9.5340e-15 + 2.1858e-15i
```

Comment: If $A$ is invertible and $B$ is not, there is no solution (a determinant argument suffices to prove this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work ! Consider the case $B = 0$. Then your solution gives $X = 0$.

You need the columns of $A$ to be in the image space of $B$. (Question : why ?).
You can also easily check that this condition is sufficient for a solution to exist.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I agree that for the trivial case, example, $B=0$ or $A=0$, the solution does not make sense.

So, you are stating that the condition should mathematically read: columns of $A$, say, $[a_i] \in \mathrm{Im}\left(B\right)$?

Comment: Yes! You can even link that to the Moore Penrose pseudo inverse since $B B^+$ is the projector on the image of $B$.